# How to remove circular doubly linked iist by using recursion?

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

i need to write recursive function which will removing all elements fron my **circular doubly linked list** by using recursion, but i dont have idea which should by the basic condition in this funcition.

```
void remove_list(struct dll_node **node)
{
    if(){
        free(*node);
        return;
    }

    if(*node){
        remove_list(&(*node)->next);
        free(*node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this is just the scope of the exercise, because you shouldn't of course need a recursive function for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just first break the circle

```
static int flag=0;
if (!flag){
    (*node->prev)->next=NULL;
    flag=1;
}
```

Then destroy it as if it is a normal double linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a pointer-to-pointer in your recursive function:

```
void remove_list(struct dll_node * node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        struct dll_node * next = node->next;
        if (next)
        {
            node->next = NULL;
            remove_list(next);
            free(next);
        }
    }
}
```